# .NET TcpSocket programming

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

What is the correct way to accept sockets in a multi connection environment in .NET?
Will the following be enough even if the load is high?

```
while (true)
{
   //block untill socket accepted
   var socket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
   DoStuff(socket) //e.g. spawn thread and read data
}
```

That is, can I accept sockets in a single thread and then handle the sockets in a thread / dataflow / whatever.
So the question is just about the accept part..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm using Async CTP and DataFlow, the current code looks like this:

```
private async void WaitForSockets()
{
    var socket = await tcpListener.AcceptSocketAsync();
    WaitForSockets();
    incomingSockets.Post(socket);
}
```

Note that what looks like a recursive call will not cause stack overflow or block.
It will simply start a new awaiter for a new socket and exit.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want the BeginAccept async operation instead of the synchroneous Accept.

And if you want to handle *high* load, you definitely don't want a thread per connection - again, you async methods.

Comment: yes thats what im doing , im playing around a bit with the TPL DataFlow library and Async CTP.. but don't quite know what the best way to accept sockets are

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at either the [Reactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern) or [Proactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proactor_pattern) pattern depending on if you wan't to block or not. I'll recommend the [Patterns for Concurrent and Networked Objects book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471606952).

Answer (score 0):

This should be fine but if the load gets even higher you might consider using the asynchronous versions of this method: [BeginAcceptSocket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginacceptsocket.aspx)/[EndAcceptSocket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.endacceptsocket.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The BeginAcceptSocket is a better choice if you want the most performant server.

More importantly, these async operations use a [Threadpool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973903.aspx) under the hood whilst in your current implementation you are creating and destroying lots of threads which is really expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to call BeginAccept(), and within OnAccept call BeginAccept right again.. This should give you the best concurrency.

The OnAccept should be something like this:

```
private void OnAccept(IAsyncResult ar)
{
   bool beginAcceptCalled = false;
   try
   {
       //start the listener again
       _listener.BeginAcceptSocket(OnAccept, null);
       beginAcceptCalled = true;
       Socket socket = _listener.EndAcceptSocket(ar);
       //do something with the socket..
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       if (!beginAcceptCalled)
       {
          //try listening to connections again
          _listener.BeginAcceptSocket(OnAccept, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What? you are using the asynchronous APM methods to perform as synchronous call? This is the most inefficient use you could have, it's better to call the sync signature if you really require sync behavior (which is not what the user asking the question probably wants in a high load scenario).

Comment: @JulianDominguez where is the code above using a synchronous call?

Comment: You are calling BeginAcceptSocket, and immediately after calling EndAcceptSocket. The later call will block the thread until the async call completes. You should only call the EndXXX methods from within the completion callback

Comment: @JulianDominguez the method above is the completion callback. Notice how it's passing itself as the callback to the beginacceptsocket.

Comment: To tell you the truth, I originally didn't notice the recursive call (but that by itself doesn't make it async). Nevertheless, you are still synchronously calling the EndAcceptSocket immediately after initiating the Begin. When the callback occurs, you will be initiating a new BeginAcceptSocket and then blocking again, which is not what you want.
Also, the error handling is very weird due to how you are linking these continuations.

Comment: @JulianDominguez .EndAcceptSocket will not block as this callback is called after the socket is already accepted, i.e. socket is already in the IAsyncResult ar. I think you're confusing it with `AcceptSocket` which is the blocking version.

Comment: This is how all APM (Aynchronous Programming Model) methods work, the End version is supposed to be used from the completion callback, otherwise it will block. In this case it is not used from the completion callback (look at the flow, the EndXXX method is being called immediately after the BeginXXX method.

Comment: More info on APM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx

More info on BeginAcceptSocket (read the remarks, it's says that it blocks until operation is completed, as design by APM): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.endacceptsocket(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @JulianDominguez as I said before the completion block is the method itself. You can't call the end method outside this block anyway as you need to pass in the AsyncResult which is only available in the completion block. The beginXXX and endXXX methods are not relating to the same socket in this case, as the beginXXX is simply telling the listener to start listening again.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter performance wise. What matters is how you communicate which each client. That handling will consume a lot more CPU than accepting sockets.

I would use `BeginAccept`/`EndAccept` for the listener socket **AND** `BeginReceive`/`EndReceive` for the client sockets.